# Neo4J Find Unreferenced Nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4j database with 2 categories of relationships: CONTAINS and REFERENCES, which is determined by a "RelationshipType" property on the relationship itself. I am trying find nodes (which by definition would have a CONTAINS relationship incoming to it from its parent), but no REFERENCES relationship.

My query is below.

```
START source=node(828)
MATCH source-[contains]->target<-[references?]-reference
WHERE contains.RelationshipType='CONTAINS'
AND references.RelationshipType='REFERENCES'
AND reference = null
RETURN target.Id
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The query doesn't work. It returns no records even though there are nodes with are part of a CONTAINS relationship, but are not part of any REFERENCES relationships.

Comment: Can you setup some data on console.neo4j.org and share the link. There is a share button on the top right.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that would both be NULL and has a property "RelationshipType", that's why the result is empty.

You can simply just specify the relationship "references' is null as follows,

```
START source=node(828)
MATCH source-[contains]->target<-[references?]-reference
WHERE contains.RelationshipType='CONTAINS' AND reference = null
RETURN target.Id
```

In the case where the "target" might have incoming relationships other than "REFERENCES", you can specify that none of the incoming relationships of the "target" should be of the property type "REFERENCE",

```
START source=node(828)
MATCH source-[contains]->target, path=target<-[references?]-reference
WHERE contains.RelationshipType='CONTAINS' AND NONE ( r in relationships(path) where r.RelationshipType='REFERENCES')
RETURN target.Id
```

Comment: That looks promising, and actually a little more readable. I wasn't aware of that part of the Cypher syntax. I'll give it a shot.